# Good Hosting Providers With Zend Framework Support

Tags: mysql, php, zend-framework

I currently use ixwebhosting for my hosting services. They're cheap and work (most of the time). The databases are horribly slow, the servers are horribly slow, and their support (though usually prompt) is tough to deal with. That being said, they're cheap, I've got like 20 domains hosted in my account, none of them are high volume, and they work *JUST* good enough- until today. This isn't meant to be a condemnation of ixwh though. Their prices are very low for what they do offer and most things work just fine, most of the time.

I need to be able to host web apps written with Zend Framework in a fairly easy fashion. The server performance can't be worse than what I've already had (a pretty low hurdle to clear), and I don't want to spend $30/mo. These are not money making websites- they're projects. My requirements are PHP 5.3, ZF support, MySQL databases, multiple domains- not much.

Who should I look at, and who should I look out for?

Comment: Zend Framework is pretty provider independent (doesn't require any speficic modules), so you can concentrate fully on the performance aspect.

Comment: The problem I've been having (and maybe it's because I'm pretty new to ZF) is that I can't change DocumentRoot to /whatever/public and I CANNOT seem to get my .htaccess correct and I can't get meaningful help from them in any way shape or form.

Comment: There is no reason your DocumentRoot has to be "public". That's just a suggestion. It could really be anything. With some hosts you have a problem with storing files outside of the document root but that can also be fixed with an .htaccess file.

Comment: This is a basically a shopping question, so either off-topic or too localized.. take your pick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know servergrove.com has expertise (techs know the framework) in ZF and there support is supposed to be top-notch. I have every intention of deploying my next project there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to vote this goes to ServerFault or SuperUser, but I am a ZF developer myself who had similar questions originally. **I recommend you look into VPS hosting**. A service such as [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) or [Rackspace](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers) will give you full root access to a clean linux distro of your choice, so you can literally do whatever you want with your server. Install random software, change webroot, create as many domains as you like, [install APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) (which will help Zend big-time since there's a lot of files to load). VPS will give you the flexibility of a dedicated server with less of the cost. If you aren't comfortable with unix admin, don't worry; slicehost's articles are amazing. They will walk you through installing anything you like. And if you go with a LTS Ubuntu distro, installing software is a breeze with aptitude. You can run a good number of Zend Framework sites on a 512 slice for $38 month.